# Hive Regexp replace with multiple strings check and replace

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

How can i achieve this in hive?

Say the input text has "Corp" and "Corporation" should be replaced to "Corp"
and the input text has "LLC", "L L C" and "L.L.C" should be replaced to "LLC"
and the input text has "INC", "INC.", "INC "and "INC ." should be replaced to "INC"
and the input text has "LP", "LP ", "LP." should be replaced to "INC"

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful, but you can do:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(replace(input, 'Corporation', 'Corp'
                                            ), '(L L C|L.L.C)', 'LLC'
                                    ), '(INC [.]|LP|LP |LP[.])', 'INC'
                     )
```

You need to be careful if the full name is HALPERNS ENTERPRISE or ALPINE CONSULTING.  But the above is what you have asked for.